# Typescript + Vue.js: Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to execute this computed method:

```
get dronesFiltered(){
        const filtered = this.drones.filter((drone) => {
            return drone.id.toString().indexOf(this.filterId) > -1 && drone.name.toLowerCase().toString().indexOf(this.filterName.toLowerCase()) > -1 && drone.status.toLowerCase().toString().indexOf(this.selectedStatus.toLowerCase()) > -1 && this.statusFly(drone.fly, drone.status).indexOf(this.selectedCurrentFly) > -1;
        });
        return filtered;
    }
```

It runs ok, but show this errors:

```
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'never'
```

It happens to status,id,name,fly (every field that i'm trying to do a filter).
How can I handle it?

Here's my component code:

```
@Component({})
export default class List extends Vue {

    drones = []
    selectedStatus = ''
    selectedCurrentFly = ''
    filterId = ''
    filterName = ''

    mounted(){
        this.listDrones(1);
    }

get dronesFiltered(){
        const filtered = this.drones.filter((drone) => {
            return drone.id.toString().indexOf(this.filterId) > -1 && drone.name.toLowerCase().toString().indexOf(this.filterName.toLowerCase()) > -1 && drone.status.toLowerCase().toString().indexOf(this.selectedStatus.toLowerCase()) > -1 && this.statusFly(drone.fly, drone.status).indexOf(this.selectedCurrentFly) > -1;
        });
        return filtered;
    }

public async listDrones(current: number) {
      try {
        const res = await dronesController.getDronesWithLimit(current);
        const resTotal = await dronesController.getDrones();
        this.totalRows = resTotal.data.length;
        this.drones = res.data;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your `drone` class?

Comment: my drone its just a drones = []

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide clarification ;)

> Since we expect --strictNullChecks to almost always be used in
>   combination with --noImplicitAny, it seems pointless to widen the type
>   of empty array literals from never[] to any[] since we'll immediately
>   report an implicit any error following the widening. It seems better
>   to preserve the more specific never[] type and require the programmer
>   to add a type annotation if the array is actually going to be
>   modified.

as explained here:
[TypeScript GitHub pull #8944](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8944)

Comment: adding `"strictNullChecks": false,` to my tsconfig.json silenced the nag for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, i just had to add this to my 'drones' variable (but I did not understand why i had to do it):

```
drones: any[] = []
```